# Create collection of N identical elements from one element using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, unit-testing, for-loop, java-stream

I want to create N identical element collection for my test. Something like this:

```
List<Future<Void>> failedFutures = Lists.newArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  failedFutures.add(failedFuture);
}
return failedFutures;
```

Is there a way how to do it in Java 8 streams in one line, i.e. to return directly the collection?

Comment: What do you think you'll achieve by adding the same item to a set 10 times?

Comment: The question you refer is not exactly what I want. I would like to have the collection directly returned from the stream chain. Just substituting the for loop doesn't make sense.

Comment: if you just want a collection with `n` copies of an item, just use `Collections.nCopies`, as described in the dupe. No need for Java 8 streams.

Comment: Sorry, it should be a list, not set (it was just an example). I will edit the question.